# cursor moveToLast() --> IndexOutOfBounds SQLiteDatabase

Tags: android, sqlite, cursor, android-sqlite

I am trying to read the item that was last added to my `SQLiteDatabase`, but I am getting a `CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException` when I try to use the `moveToLast()` method.  Strings are added to the Database in a `Fragment`.  When the strings are added, I separate class (not an `Activity`/`Fragment` ) is supposed to create a Toast with the last item that was added.

Here is the code:

In the Fragment:

```
HistoryDataBaseSQL mDbHelper = new HistoryDataBaseSQL(getActivity()); // This gets access to my SQL
            SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(ConstructData.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID, counter);
            values.put(ConstructData.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, content_title); // content_title is a variable
```

This is part of my helper class:

```
public static abstract class ConstructData implements BaseColumns {

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "history";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID = "entryid";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME_TITLE = "title";
```

This is my DataBase class:

```
public class HistoryDataBaseSQL extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "history.db";

        private static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
        private static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
        private static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
            "CREATE TABLE " + ConstructData.TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                    ConstructData._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                    ConstructData.COLUMN_NAME_ENTRY_ID + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
            ConstructData.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE + TEXT_TYPE +
             // Any other options for the CREATE command, rem to add comma_sep to split
            " )";

        public HistoryDataBaseSQL(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
        }
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
                onCreate(db);
        }
        public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
        }

    }
```

This is the class that tries to create the `Toast`:

```
HistoryDataBaseSQL mDbHelper = new HistoryDataBaseSQL(getContext); // This gets access to my SQL
    SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

    String[] projection = {
            ConstructData._ID,
            ConstructData.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE            
            };

    Cursor c = db.query(
            ConstructData.TABLE_NAME,  
            projection,                            
         null,                                  
        null,                        
        null,                                     
         null,                                   
         null                              
            );
    c.moveToLast(); 
     String string = null;

                string = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ConstructData.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE)); // If I comment this out, there is not exception

    Toast.makeText(getContext, "Title is: " + string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    c.close();
```

Comment: Are you sure that you are getting the db instance from the same thread  or synchronously?

Comment: @forcelain I haven't added any threads anywhere yet - so yes

Comment: I added an  if(c.moveToLast()) {} And put a log in there, but it is never true, so the cursor must be empty

Comment: I think you forgot to insert/replace your content values in DB. Use db.replace (TABLE_NAME, null, values) (or something like that) right after the last values.put(...) in the fragment code

Comment: @forcelain Yeah, I think your right - thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You trigger the exception because the query return no result.

It is not recommend that to read database frequently. The database is use for the persistence of data.

You you can still use you DataModel. After you add a item, you add it to `DataModel` and save the data into database.

You can fetch the saved data into `DataModel` when the app is laughed next time.

Comment: Thanks srain. If I remove an item from the list with list.remove(), how can it be removed from the database as well?

Comment: I saw there is a `_id` field in you table, you can use a delete sql text to to that, for example: `delete from table_name where id = 1`